# Odata json query builder transformation. Recursion?

Tags: recursion, odata, breeze

I'm currently building a query builder for Odata.

I took inspiration from this project :

http://mfauveau.github.io/angular-query-builder/.

I do have now a json interpretation of the query.

But the framework Im using to work with odata has a different format.

My problem is that the query could be infinitly nested.

I need this kind of output :

```
{ or: [
    age: { ">": 40 }, 
    and: [
      { lastName: { startsWith: 'A'}},
      { hireDate: { '<': new Date(2010, 0, 1) }}
    ]
  ]
}
```

And I have this input :

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "condition": "=",
      "field": "ID",
      "data": "1",
      "$$hashKey": "object:244"
    },
    {
      "condition": "=",
      "field": "ID",
      "data": "1",
      "$$hashKey": "object:310"
    },
    {
      "group": {
        "operator": "AND",
        "rules": [
          {
            "condition": "=",
            "field": "ID",
            "data": "1",
            "$$hashKey": "object:392"
          },
          {
            "condition": "=",
            "field": "ID",
            "data": "1",
            "$$hashKey": "object:456"
          }
        ]
      },
      "$$hashKey": "object:363"
    }
  ],
  "operator": "OR"
}
```

I 'd need some advice to solve this problem.

So if you have a link or some ideas that could help me.

I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

```
   function convertQueryBuilderToBreeze(filtre) {
      var jsonObject = {};
      if (filtre.rules && filtre.operator) {
        jsonObject[filtre.operator] = filtre.rules.map(function (rule) {
          if (rule.condition) {
            var condition = {};
            var obj = {};
            obj[rule.condition] = rule.data;
            condition[rule.field] = obj;
            return condition;
          } else if (rule.group) {
            return convertQueryBuilderToBreeze(rule.group);
          }
        });
      }
      return jsonObject;
    }
```